# Is it possible to switch port binding between docker containers without downtime?

Tags: docker

Scenario:

There is a container running with image version 1.0 and exposed port 8080 on localhost 80. The new version of the image is available, and there is a need to switch those versions. **No, any orchestration tool is running** ( Kubernetes, OpenShift etc...).

Is it possible to start a container with version 1.1 make it run without a problem
Please, keep in mind that I don't want to keep it simple, no replication, etc. 
Simply docker container with the binded port to localhost.

Questions:
1. Is it possible **to switch exposing of port between containers without downtime**?
2. If not, is there is any mechanism implemented with docker (free edition) to do such switch?

Answer (score 1):

Without downtime, you'd need a second replica of the service up an running, and a proxy in front of that service that's listening to user requests and routing from one to the other. Both Swarm Mode and Kubernetes provide this capability with similar tools, the port being exposed is indirectly connected to the app via either an application reverse proxy, or some iptables rules and ipvs entries in the kernel.

Out of the box, recent versions of docker include support for Swarm Mode with nothing additional to install. You can run a simple `docker swarm init` to start a single node swarm cluster in less than a second. And then instead of `docker-compose up` you switch to `docker stack deploy -c docker-compose.yml $stack_name` to manage your projects with almost the same compose file. For swarm mode, you'll want to be on version 3 of the compose file syntax.

For a v3 syntax compose file in swarm mode that has no outage on an update, you'll want healthcheck's defined in your image to monitor the application and report back when it's ready to receive requests. Then you'll want a deploy section of the compose file to either have multiple replicas for HA, or at least configure a single replica to have a "start-first" policy to ensure the new service is up before stopping the old one. See the compose docs for settings to adjust: https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#update_config

For an application based reverse proxy in docker, I really do like traefik, but more to allow me to run multiple http based container services with a single port opened. This allows me to mapping requests based off the hostname/path/http header to the right container, while at the same time giving features to migrate between different versions with weighting of which backend to use so you can do more than a simple round-robin load balancing during an upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

There is no mechanism native to Docker that would allow you replace one container with another with *no* interruption.  On the other hand, the duration of the interruption can probably be measured in milliseconds; whether or not this is *really* an issue for you depends entirely on your application.

You can get the behavior you want by introducing a dynamic reverse proxy such as [Traefik](https://traefik.io/) into your configuration. The proxy binds to host ports and handles requests from remote systems, then distributes those requests to one or more backend containers.

You can create and remove backend containers as you please, and as long as at least one is running your application will be available.  For your specific use case, this means that you can start the new version of your application first, then retire the old one, all without any interruption in service.